# Autosuggestion Javascript/PHP/AJAX Code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest

Consider an array holding some values

```
array = {'microsoft','micromax', 'miniclip','michael jackson','million','milky way'}
```

When an user start typing the text, say s/he is trying to enter `million`. When user start typing `'mi'` the above suggestion in the array will be shown to the user.

**My Question:**

Let us assume user is typing the word 'mini clip', by typo s/he started to type `'mni' or 'minc' or 'nim' or 'imn' or 'nim' instead of 'min',` this scenario also need to show the suggestion to the user. Becasue, anyway those typed characters are available in the word 'miniclip'. Typo is common for all entry level users/common users. So I need code in javascript/php/ajax/opensource library to suit this scenario.

Comment: You seriously need `AJAX`

Comment: Are you looking for an algo or is an out of the box solution also ok? If so, give solr a try http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester

Comment: yes gentleman, we need AJAX

Comment: Have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163775/php-create-ajax-auto-suggest

Comment: But when an user started to type 'mni' or 'minc' or 'nim' or 'imn' or 'nim' instead of 'min' due to typo, this scenario also need to show the suggestion `'miniclip'` to the user, that is my question.

Comment: Use ajax and regex....

Comment: any sample code in regex, I dono regex

Comment: One thing I'm not clear on here... Do you already have the _auto-suggestion feature_ implemented and wish, now, to extend it with mistyped words? Or are you looking for a complete solution?

Comment: looking for entire solution Steven

Comment: Have you already got the functionality to _grab_ the user input from a text box?? If not how are users inputting text? (e.g. text box, textarea, content-editable div/span)

Comment: from the input box only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## HTML

```
<form action=""><input type="text" name="word" id="word"></form>
<div id="auto"></div>
```

## JS

```
$(function(){
    $('#word').keyup(function(e){
        var input = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "autocomplete.php",
            data: {word: input},
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                var outWords = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#auto').html('');

                for(x = 0; x < outWords.length; x++){
                    $('#auto').prepend('<div>'+outWords[x]+'</div>'); //Fills the #auto div with the options
                }
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Don't forget to link `jQuery`...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### N.B.

You would need to do something like add an `onclick` event to the child `div`s of `#auto` to replace the contents of `#word` (the input field).

## PHP

```
$array  = array('microsoft','micromax', 'miniclip','michael jackson','million','milky way');
$input  = urldecode($_GET['word']); //Get input word/phrase (decode in case of spaces etc.)
$length = strlen($input);           //Get length of input word
// $min    = $length - 1;              //Length of word - 1
// $max    = $length + 1;              //Length of word + 1

$returned = preg_grep('/^(['.$input.']{'.$length.'}.*)$/i', $array); //Find matches in $array and return as array
$returned = array_values($returned);                                //Re-index from 0

echo json_encode($returned); //Returm json string to ajax call
```

### Regex

```
/^([$input]{$length}.*)$/i
```

1. `/` => Starting delimter
2. `^` => Start of string
3. `(` => Start a capture group
4. `[` => Start a character class
5. `$input` => Add the input word to the character class
6. `]` => End the character class (4)
7. `{$length}` => Set length of string to match character class against (length of input word)
8. `.*` => Match any **following** characters 0 or more times
9. `)` => End capture group (3)
10. `$` => Match end of string
11. `/` => Ending delimeter
12. `i` => Modifier for case insensitivity

### Min/Max

I have included the commented `$min` and `$max` variables... An added feature that I thought you *might* like... You would implement them by changing:

```
{'.$length.'}          <-- Change this
{'.$min.','.$max.'}    <--To that
{'.$length.','.$max.'} <-- Or that (or another combination)
```

#### Example

An example might best show how this works...

Suppose an auto correct array of:

```
$array = array('loser', 'loses', 'losing');
```

and an input of:

```
lose
```

Currently (`{'.$length.'}`) the code will return:

```
loser
loses
```

But if you change it to `{'.$min.','.$max.'}` (and uncomment `$min` / `$max`); it will return:

```
losing
loser
loses
```

Comment: I should also point out that this is a _crude_ method; while fine for small word lists it will output large numbers of suggestions (with no filtering) for longer lists and when more (different) characters are in the input field.

Comment: First of all Thanks Steven,I uncommented the 
<br>
    $min    = $length - 1;              //Length of word - 1
    $max    = $length + 1;              //Length of word + 1

I am getting the following 3 issues.

I. When I type `"milyk w"` it shows the suggestion `"milky way"`, it is very nice but when I tried to type `"milyk wy"`, it is not showing the suggestion.

II. When am erasing all characters using backspace,  the firebug throws a, 

    **Syntax Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character**
<br>
III. I have tried with following typos

Comment: 1. mcroisoft - Ok
2. micro soft - Not Ok
3. micro sfot - Not Ok
4. microsotf - Ok
5. mirco sfto - Not Ok
6. icro soft - Not Ok
7. mivro soft (mercy) - Not Ok
8. microsogt (mercy) - Not Ok

Comment: Comments for Not Ok:
2. micro soft - tried with space
3. micro sfot - But 's','f','o','t' avilable in 'microsoft'
5. mirco sfto - But 's','f','t','o' avilable in 'microsoft'
6. icro soft - Missed first letter 'M', but remaining character are available in 'microsoft'
7. mixro soft (mercy) - One wrong letter 'v' instead of 'c', because x is present previous to c
8. microsogt (mercy) - One wrong letter 'g' instead of 'f', because g is present next to f

Comment: Okay the `JSON.parse` error is an easy fix.. Add `if(empty($_GET['word'])){exit;}` to the start of the script. The error occurs because a couple of functions return errors when the input is empty.

Comment: As for the `not OK` examples above.. I assume you mean that they are **not** showing the expected suggestion?

Comment: Okay, I'm confused.. If you uncommented the `$min` and `$max`; all of the above should work (except for 7/8). Did you not change `{'.$length.'}` to `{'.$min.','.$max.'}`?

Comment: Yes, I have uncommented. $length = strlen($input);           //Get length of input word
$min    = $length - 1;              //Length of word - 1
$max    = $length + 1;              //Length of word + 1 and you can see the output here 
Check [this][1]


  [1]: http://einterviewquestions.com/addbuya/mytestdrive/autocomplete/autocompletion.html

Comment: But you haven't hanged the regex?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40046/discussion-between-einterview-and-steven)

Comment: I went offline before seeing your message; have now replied with clarification on what you need to do to make it work

Comment: I have a doubt. when i type `micros`, i expect `micrsoft` to pop up but along with `microsoft` , `micromax` is a also displayed. Its the same for `milky way`, if i type `milk` or `milky` even `million` is displayed. @Steven do you know why this behaviour? this has to do something with the `preg_grep`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Here is index.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="testid" id="testid" >
        <div id="result">

        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var xhr = null;

        $('#testid').on("keyup", function(){
            if(xhr !== null) { 
                xhr.abort();
            }
            var searchkey = $(this).val();

           xhr = $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "ajax_request.php",
            data: { searchkey: searchkey }
          })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                $('#result').html(msg);
            });
        });

        $(document.body).on('click', ".listitem", function(e){
            var values = $(this).html();
            $('#testid').val(values);
            $('#result').html('');
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
</html>
```

And this one is your ajax_request.php

```
<?php
$arr = array("Shailesh Sonare", "Hello World", "Hello Universe");

$html = "<ul>";

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $html .= "<li class='listitem'>" . $value . "</li>";
}

$html .= "</ul>";

echo $html;
```